# How to remove the space between two Labels?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two Labels, and I want to remove the vertical space between them.

[There is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAImB.png)

I tried to set Margin="0", but the space appear anyway.

```
<Label Text="Label 01" TextColor="White" FontSize="25" Margin="0" />
<Label Text="Label 02" TextColor="White" FontSize="25" Margin="0" />
```

Comment: try setting their HeightRequest

Comment: What is the parent of those labels?

Comment: The parent is a StackLayout

Comment: With the HeightRequest the space has been reduced, but still exists a little space.

Comment: Also keep in mind that StackLayouts have a default 6 pixel space between each element.

Comment: You can set the "Spacing" property for its parent layout to 0 to remove the space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels have, per default, an extra padding in top. Also, careful with the container you are putting them in, remove spacing in case of a StackLayout and RowSpacing in case of grids.

You can override label extra padding with a custom renderer like this one:

```
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using XF.LabelPadding.Droid.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public MyLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control?.SetIncludeFontPadding(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Maui, and what I did is set the padding to minus.

```
<Label Text="SING IN" TextColor="#FFFFFF" FontSize="90" Padding="-5,-20,-5,-5"></Label>
```